# How do I remotely administer VMWare ESXi 4.0 server

Tags: vmware-esxi

What do I need to remotely administer VMWare ESXi 4.0 server?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You manage it using the VMware VI Client that you can download by pointing a browser at the ip-address you gave the ESXi server when you built it.

Comment: thank you. I did that, and I have one more issue after installing VMWare vSphere Client I got "Error parsing the "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" "clients.xml" file"

Comment: I am running XP with SP3

Comment: I figure out that, fixed this by installing client on virtual machine with bare XP(SP3). It looks like vSphere client is broken on my host OS with all latest updates

Comment: @volody Yes, one of the recent .NET updates for XP broke the vSphere client. Uninstall that, and it should start working.

Comment: Just yesterday I noticed very interesting thing. Not sure if it's because of ESXi 4.1 update 1 or it was there before, BUT, when you navigate to the ESXI's webpage and click on download Vsphere client, you actually getting redirected to the VMware's website.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare has released an update for the vSphere client to correct this issue, see http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022611

This had been an issue on Win7 for a while, that .Net update must have brought it down to XP also.

Comment: Yes, I had fixed that. I have downloaded the latest ESXi 4.0 with Update 1, and vSphere client from this distribution works fine.